# Finding a Numerical Solution to a Linear Combination Inequality

Tags: numerics, linear-algebra, vector, inequalities

Can I use Mathematica to find a value for $\alpha$ that satisfies the below linear combination inequality? If so, how?

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\
-1 \\
-1
\end{bmatrix}
<
\begin{bmatrix}
g_1 \\
\vdots \\
g_n
\end{bmatrix}
+
\alpha
\begin{bmatrix}
m_1 \\
\vdots \\
m_n
\end{bmatrix}
<
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
\vdots \\
1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I do not care as much about finding an algebraic expression as I do about finding a numerical solution for $\alpha$ given a set of values $g_1, \dots, g_n$ and $m_1, \dots, m_n$.

Furthermore, an important point is that I would be happy as long as the value of $\alpha$ is such that the above inequality is almost true. In other words, if an exact solution does not exist (which is rather likely) I would like to find a value for $\alpha$ that minimizes the error in the inequality (Currently, I cannot find a more precise way to express what I mean by the "error" in the inequality.)

*Update 1:* Perhaps one could think of minimizing the "error" in the above inequality in a "least squares sense". After all, if we omit one of the outer vectors, say $[-1 \ -1 \ -1]$, and replace $<$ by $=$, we would have an overdetermined system of equations and could attempt to find a value for $\alpha$ by the Method of Least Squares.

For example, the system
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
g_1 \\
\vdots \\
g_n
\end{bmatrix}
+
\alpha
\begin{bmatrix}
m_1 \\
\vdots \\
m_n
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
\vdots \\
1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
could be rewritten on the form $A\vec{x} = \vec{b}$ as follows:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
g_1 & m_1 \\
\vdots & \vdots \\
g_n & m_n
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
\alpha
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
1 \\
1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

*Update 2:* Since I want all of the entries in my resulting vector to lie between $-1$ and $1$, I believe that I could find a good value for $\alpha$ by solving the subsequent system of $n$ equations in one unknown:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
g_1 \\
\vdots \\
g_n
\end{bmatrix}
+
\alpha
\begin{bmatrix}
m_1 \\
\vdots \\
m_n
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
\vdots \\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I believe that the problem proposed at the very start of my post can be reduced to finding a solution to the above system using the Method of Least Squares. I believe this because $0$ lies precisely in the middle between $-1$ and $1$, and the least squares solution to the above system finds the value of $\alpha$ that will result in all entries of the linear combination being as close to 0 as possible in the "least squares sense". Intuitively, getting all entires as close to zero as possible (or, in other words, as close to precisely in the middle between $-1$ and $1$ as possible) appears to be a very similar problem as the problem of getting all entires to lie within the interval $[-1, 1]$.

Ultimately, I think that solving the overdetermined system

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
m_1 \\
\vdots \\
m_n
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
-g_1 \\
\vdots \\
-g_n
\end{bmatrix}
$$
using the Method of Least Squares should also be a solution to the original problem. Can you find any holes in this approach?

*Update 3:* My proposed approach seems to work fairly well. A test on vectors with 48000 randomly generated entries between $-1$ and $1$ resulted in $7$ entires (~0.15%) that violate the inequality in the resulting linear combination. If I just add together the vectors without using my approach to prepare them, 12 064 entires (~25%) violate the inequality.

Comment: Probably better to ask another question, rather than changing a question, particularly once it has been answered.

Comment: @mikado In my question, I say "if an exact solution does not exist (which is rather likely) I would like to find a value for  that minimizes the error in the inequality". The provided answer only works if an exact solution exist, and thus it does not fully answer my original question. Furthermore, I have not changed my question in updating it, only provided a possible to it answer and asked for confirmation that it is correct. Please point out to me what you think should be a separate question; maybe I am overlooking it.

Answer (score 5):

As an example, you could write this quite literally

```
eqn = {-1, -1, -1} < {3, 4, 5} + α {5, 6, 7} < {1, 1,  1}
(* {-1, -1, -1} < {3 + 5 α, 4 + 6 α, 5 + 7 α} < {1, 1, 1} *)

Reduce[Thread[eqn], α]
(* -(4/5) < α < -(4/7) *)
```

If your inequalities are infeasible, you will need to decide how you would define a "best" solution.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what `Reduce[Thread[eqn], α]` does?

Comment: @K.Claesson `Reduce` is a general function for solving equations.  `Thread` turns expressions involving lists into lists of expressions.  Try evaluating `Thread[eqn]` to see the effect.